# Checking file existence on FTP server

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

Is there an efficient way to check the existence of a file on a FTP server? I'm using Apache Commons Net. I know that I can use the `listNames` method of `FTPClient` to get all the files in a specific directory and then I can go over this list to check if a given file exists, but I don't think it's efficient especially when the server contains a lot of files.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`listFiles(String pathName)` should work just fine for a single file.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, I check the FTPFile[] array length to know if the file exists.

Comment: It may return a lot  of data if `pathName` is a directory containing a lot of files.

Answer (score 18):

Using a full path to a file in [`listFiles`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles(java.lang.String)) (or [`mlistDir`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistDir(java.lang.String))) call, as the accepted answer shows, should indeed work:

```
String remotePath = "/remote/path/file.txt";
FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(remotePath);
if (remoteFiles.length > 0)
{
    System.out.println("File " + remoteFiles[0].getName() + " exists");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("File " + remotePath + " does not exists");
}
```

The [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959) in the section 4.1.3 in the part about the `LIST` command says:

> If the pathname specifies a file then the server should send current information on the file.

Though if you are going to check for many files, this will be rather ineffective. A use of the `LIST` command actually involves several commands, waiting for their responses, and mainly, opening a data connection. Opening a new TCP/IP connection is a costly operation, even more so, when an encryption is used (what is a must these days).

Also `LIST` command is even more ineffective for testing an existence of a folder, as it results in a transfer of a complete folder contents.

---

More efficient is to use [`mlistFile`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistFile(java.lang.String)) (`MLST` command), if the server supports it:

```
String remotePath = "/remote/path/file.txt";
FTPFile remoteFile = ftpClient.mlistFile(remotePath);
if (remoteFile != null)
{
    System.out.println("File " + remoteFile.getName() + " exists");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("File " + remotePath + " does not exists");
}
```

This method *can* be used to test an existence of a directory.

`MLST` command does not use a separate connection (contrary to `LIST`).

---

If the server does not support `MLST` command, you can *abuse* [`getModificationTime`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getModificationTime(java.lang.String)) (`MDTM` command) or [`getSize`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getSize(java.lang.String)) (`SIZE` command):

```
String timestamp = ftpClient.getModificationTime(remotePath);
if (timestamp != null)
{
    System.out.println("File " + remotePath + " exists");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("File " + remotePath + " does not exists");
}
```

This method *cannot* be used to test an existence of a directory.

Comment: Please note that as of 3.8.0 of Apache commons-net, both `mlistFile` and `getModificationTime` will return `null` if the used commands (MLST or MDTM) are not recognized by the FTP server (though hiding the possible existing of a file whilst returning `null`): https://github.com/apache/commons-net/blob/rel/commons-net-3.8.0/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.java#L3010 https://github.com/apache/commons-net/blob/rel/commons-net-3.8.0/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.java#L1857

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me.

Code did not work:

```
String remotePath = "/remote/path/file.txt";
FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(remotePath);
```

Instead, this works for me:

```
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/remote/path");
FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles("file.txt");
```

Comment: That's just a peculiarity of your particular FTP server. For majority of servers, there's no difference between the two code snippets.

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean isDirectory(String dstPath) throws IOException {
    return ftpsClient.changeWorkingDirectory(dstPath);
}

public boolean exists(String dstPath) throws IOException {
    if (isDirectory(dstPath)) {
        return true;
    }
    FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpsClient.listFiles(dstPath);
    return remoteFiles != null && remoteFiles.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: One wouldn't expect a function like `exists` to have side effects.

Comment: I would like to always use absolute path instead of working directory

Comment: Fine. But please clearly acknowledge this constraint in your answer.