# How to check file Exist or not?

Tags: file, grails, groovy, ftp

Here I'm trying to check whether the file exist or not.but the below code doesn't return anything and 
also get the error at this line

Error line  : Boolean t = fileslist.Exists()

```
   start()
    def start(){
    def store;
    boolean success;
    def ftpClient = new FTPClient()
    ftpClient.connect(server)
    ftpClient.login(user,pass) 
     ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
     FTPFile[] fileslist = ftpClient.listFiles("/Sample.txt")
     ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)
     filelist.each{
          it.exists()
       }  
     ftpClient.disconnect() 

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show what you want to do with the file if it exists... What are you trying to do? Also, why are you listing files using a file name path?

Comment: I'm just checking  whether the file exist in ftp or not

Comment: I have posted a [more verbose answer to an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10482204/850848#49877234).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can verify that a file exists by checking that the returned array is not empty:

```
FTPFile[] fileslist = ftpClient.listFiles("/Sample.txt")

if(fileslist)
    print "File exists"
else(fileslist)
    print "File does not exist"
```

Alternatively, you can check the results and find the name you're interested in:

```
FTPFile[] fileslist = ftpClient.listFiles("/")

def matchedFiles = Arrays.asList(fileslist).grep(it.name == 'Sample.txt')
```

The below will return a list with matching file objects

Comment: check my updated question please i got error and doesn't return anything

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show what you want to do with the file if it exists... What are you trying to do? Also, why are you listing files using a file name path?

Comment: You may need to confirm that an exception is not raised when the file isn't found, in which case it may be preferable to use the second alternative.

Comment: Thank you so much Ernest Kiwele it works

Comment: Edited... with an `else` block

Comment: Is it possible to get status codes if file exist like