# Is there any way we can override a file preset in remote server using java FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp, java-io, ftp-client

Is there any way we can override a file preset in remote server using java FTPClient. I have tried googling for some information but couldnt get any. Some help would be really helpful.

Comment: What is *"file preset"*?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, Its present, spelling mistake.

Comment: See my answer to [Checking file existence on FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10482204/850848#49877234).