# FTP list command throws MalformedServerReplyException: Truncated server reply

Tags: java, file-upload, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have a Java application using Apache Commons Net to upload mp3 to my FTP server.

However, if it is a new file, it will throw a `MalformedServerReplyException`. If it is an existing file, it will upload and overwrite perfectly.

The exception is already thrown at line:

```
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

However, I checked in Wireshark and the command `TYPE I` goes fine.

Can someone help me with this?

Here an image of Wireshark up until the exception:
[image]

```
public static void transferFile(File file, boolean OverwriteAllowed) {
    FtpLogin();
    try {
        System.out.println('\n');
        System.out.println("DEBUG: "+ file.toString());

        boolean isNewFile = false;
        String filePath = getFtpPathToMusic() + file.getName();

        ftpClient.sendNoOp();
        showServerReply();

        if (ftpClient.listFiles(filePath).length > 0) {
            System.out.println("File exists, and overwrite allowed is: " + OverwriteAllowed);
        } else {
            isNewFile = true;
          //  System.out.println("File does not exist yet on server");
        }

        if (OverwriteAllowed || isNewFile) {
            ftpClient.setStrictReplyParsing(false);
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            showServerReply();
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);


            OutputStream outputStream = ftpClient.storeFileStream(filePath);
            byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
            int read;
            long remaining = file.length();
            long transferred = 0;

            System.out.println("Transfering data...");
            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
                remaining -= read;
                transferred += read;
                System.out.print('\r');
                System.out.print("Remaining: " + remaining/1024 + "kb | Transferred: " + transferred/1024 + "kb");
            }
            System.out.println();
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();

            boolean completed = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
            if (completed) {
                showServerReply();
                System.out.println("File " + filePath + " uploaded succesfully");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("File is skipped");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showServerReply();
    }

}
```

Expected: successful upload
Actual: MalformedServerReplyException

```
org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException: Truncated server reply: 
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:332)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:300)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:523)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:648)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.type(FTP.java:1119)
at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.setFileType(FTPClient.java:1559)
at FtpSupport.FtpTransfer.transferFile(FtpTransfer.java:116)
at Home.ConverterGuiHome$convertMp3FilesExecute.actionPerformed(ConverterGuiHome.java:144)
```

At request - the full (FTP) logging:

```
Getting files from: /ideaProjects/GsmMp3Manager/src/main/Mp3Files/export
Creating mp3 object from file: 377 test.mp3
220 DiskStation FTP server ready.
SERVER: 220 DiskStation FTP server ready.
NOOP
200 NOOP command successful.
SERVER: 200 NOOP command successful.
USER *******
331 Password required for Barbet.
PASS *******
230 User Barbet logged in.
SERVER: 230 User Barbet logged in.
LOGGED IN SERVER
File listing in directory  :
SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (77,164,214,202,216,242)
LIST 
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 'file list'.
226 Transfer complete.
[home]      4096        2018-12-12 00:00:00
[Spotlight]     4096        2018-11-17 00:00:00
[music]     4096        2018-11-22 00:00:00
[Mission Possible]      4096        2013-11-13 00:00:00
DEBUG:377 test.mp3


DEBUG: src/main/Mp3Files/export/377 test.mp3
NOOP
200 NOOP command successful.
SERVER: 200 NOOP command successful.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (77,164,214,202,216,241)
LIST /Spotlight/muziek/377 test.mp3
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 'file list'.
550 /Spotlight/muziek/377 test.mp3: No such file or directory.
TYPE I
org.apache.commons.net.MalformedServerReplyException: Truncated server reply: 
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:332)
    (... see stack trace)

 Close ftp session
QUIT
200 Type set to I.
SERVER: 200 Type set to I.
```

Comment: Could you extend your question with detailed stacktrace? Do you use `FTP` protocol or `SFTP`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using FTP. I added the stacktrace in the origional post.

Comment: I have added the logger, and this only confirms what I also saw in wireshark. Still thanks, adding a logger is always a good idea, I didn't know it was this easy.

Comment: Yes, I added it in

Comment: I believe that your question title is not correct. Your problem actually has nothing to do with *"upload"*. The problem happens already with `listFiles`, not with `storeFileStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have to be confirmed by a full Wireshark dump, but I believe the log file indicates that the `550` response to `LIST` command is followed by two newlines. The Apache `FTPClient` treats the second "line" as an (invalid) response to the following `TYPE I` command. So it looks like a server-side bug.

Did you try using other method to check for a file existence?
See my answer to [Checking file existence on FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10482204/850848#49877234)
(as the answer says, using `listFiles` to check for the file existence is actually a violation of FTP protocol).

Comment: Amazing, I hadn't figured this out myself. Thank you so much :). I'm a beginning programmer, I learned a lot from this. Have a great weekend!

Comment: Still one question, you mentioned that this could be confirmed by Wireshark. What would you expect to see there? Just for learning and understanding :).

Comment: Try using *"follow TCP stream"* functionality of Wireshark to see if there are indeed two newlines.