# Perl Net::FTP not lists particular file

Tags: perl, ftp

I am trying to list the file of remote host using Net::FTP Perl module. Later I want to download it using `put` command.

Will it possible to list the particular file using `ls` command

Syntax I am using is:

```
$remote_dir = "/home/user/test_dir/";
$ftp->cwd($remote_dir);
$file_name = "test.txt";
print $ftp->ls($file_name);
```

This file is exists in remote server when I tried checking it manually. But listing is not happening.

`ftp->ls();` is used for only listing the directory contents or can it be used to list the particular file from a directory as I mentioned above?

Comment: You need to determine where the FTP server's root directory is, and establish the path from that root to the file you are interested in.  It is unlikely the FTP root is the filesystem root directory, so it is unlikely a remote path of `/home/user/test_dir/` would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

> `ftp->ls();` is used for only listing the directory contents **or can it be used to list the particular file from a directory**

From [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP#ls-(-[-DIR-]-)):

> **ls ( [ DIR ] )**
>   Get a directory listing of DIR, or the current directory.

Thus, it is clearly documented to list a **directory**, not a specific regular file.

Comment: So that means after putting a directory contents into an array, I should pick the file?```@files = $ftp->ls();
foreach ( @files ) {
 print "Found : $file_name\n" if( $_ =~ /$file_name/);
}```

Comment: @vinodk89: correct, if you want to know if a file exists in a directory then you need to get a listing of the directory and look for the file.

Comment: > Thus, it is clearly documented to list a directory, not a specific regular file.
This is simply not true as I just tested with my own ftp server.

So there must be another issue.

Comment: @Skeeve: `ls` is implemented in terms of the FTP `NLST` command. This command is defined in [RFC 959](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959) as *"The pathname should specify a
            __directory or other system-specific file group descriptor__;"*, i.e. a directory or something similar (OS dependent). A specific FTP server might actually also support a regular file name there but this case is out of the specification so you should not rely on this and you should not generalize on what you see with a single server to what you can expect from other servers.

Comment: @Skeeve Steffen is right. For similar questions (for other languages), see for example [FTP directory partial listing with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282753/850848) or [Checking file existence on FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10482204/850848).

Comment: Thanks to Martin Prikryl and also @Steffen Ullrich for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich. Now I am able to list the files from a particular directory but not all the files. Actually directory is having almost 1500+ files but array(`@files`) is giving count 900+. Why its not giving the exact count of files which it has in the directory. Is there any restrictions in listing ?

Comment: @vinodk89: There is neither a restriction in Net::FTP nor is such restriction in the standard. It is not clear from your description what exactly is behaving wrong here - it might be that the data connection breaks but it might also be that the server does not send the information about all the files.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have trouble retrieving files from remote server using `get` command of `Net::FTP` module. With `Net::SFTP` its working. So any guesses what would be the reason?

Comment: @vinodk89: please don't ask new questions in a comment. Ask a new question instead with sufficient details (code, debug output). Apart from that Net::SFTP is using a completely different protocol: SFTP is based on SSH not FTP.